adding new column to dataframe of Array[String] type based on condition, spark scala
I have the following dataframe -



colA
colB




A1
B1


A2
B2


A3
B3



colA: String, colB: String
Also, I have a Map[String, Array[String]]
I want to add a new column 'colC' containing values of Map corresponding to the values present in colB (reference column)
map that i have Map[String, Array[String]]("B1" -> Array("C1","C2"), "B2" -> Array("C3","C4"))
So, I expect something like this -



colA
colB
colC




A1
B1
(C1, C2)


A2
B2
(C3, C4)


A3
B3
(B3)



import sqlContext.implicits._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val col = List("colA","colB")
val test_schema = StructType(col.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
val data = Seq(Seq("A1","B1"), Seq("A2","B2"), Seq("A3","B3"))
val rowsRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).map(Row.fromSeq)
var df = spark.createDataFrame(rowsRDD, test_schema)

val map = Map[String, Array[String]]("B1" -> Array("C1", "C2"), "B2" -> Array("C3", "C4"))

df = df.withColumn("colC", when(map.contains($"colB"), map($"colB")).otherwise(Array($"colB")))

got this error -

:60: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
required: String

How to add complex data type such as Map or Array to a column in spark (scala) dataframe

Although you can use maps directly (e.g. Quality's support) it's often just easier (and faster) to provide Spark a dataset representing the map e.g.:
val map = Map[String, Array[String]]("B1" -> Array("C1", "C2"), "B2" -> Array("C3", "C4"))
val mapAsDF = map.toSeq.toDF("key","value")
df = df.join(mapAsDF, $"colB" === $"key", "left_outer")
df.show

yielding:
+----+----+----+--------+
|colA|colB| key|   value|
+----+----+----+--------+
|  A1|  B1|  B1|[C1, C2]|
|  A2|  B2|  B2|[C3, C4]|
|  A3|  B3|NULL|    NULL|
+----+----+----+--------+

now you can use a simple if to correct your new colC:
df = df.select($"colA", $"colB", when(isnull($"value"), array($"colB")).otherwise($"value").as("colC"))
df.show

yielding:
+----+----+--------+
|colA|colB|    colC|
+----+----+--------+
|  A1|  B1|[C1, C2]|
|  A2|  B2|[C3, C4]|
|  A3|  B3|    [B3]|
+----+----+--------+


Hi Chris, Thanks for the answer. I applied it and it is working fine. :)

awesome, if you are using 3.5 you can also use ifnull instead of when otherwise there, if you are happy with an answer you should accept it though.

Hey @Chris, accepted the answer, I was using this for first time, I'll keep that in mind from now on. Thanks a lot :)
